# How to insert hyperlink into text using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I'd like to make an `Insert Link` button. Here is what I came up with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function HyperLink(elementID, openTag, closeTag) {
    var textArea = $('#' + elementID);
    var len = textArea.val().length;
    var start = textArea[0].selectionStart;
    var end = textArea[0].selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end);
    var replacement = openTag + selectedText + closeTag;
    textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + replacement + textArea.val().substring(end, len));
}

$('#btnHyperlink').click(function() {
    HyperLink("id_description", "<a>", "</a>");
});
});
```

The snippent above embraces text with `<a>...</a>`, however I don't know how to insert href to the text.

Appreciate your help.

**Note:**

I want links to be dynamically added to the text, as this button is going to be used in a simple text editor.

Comment: Where do you get the value for the href from?

Comment: @epascarello It is to be submitted by user, in an input field/window.

Comment: So pass it in when you are building the hyperlink???

Comment: So, is the function turning an url text into an hyperlink?

Comment: @epascarello not sure what you mean, but basically I want to replicate insert link functionality of SO.

Comment: @Eagle no it should turn any selected text to anchored text.

Comment: So prompt the user and concat the href to the method you have. Seems simple. `HyperLink("id_description", "<a href='" + yourVariable + "'>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then how about:

```
$('#btnHyperlink').click(function() {
    var href = prompt("Insert url");
    if(href != "" && href != null)
    {
        HyperLink("id_description", href);
    }
});
```

And the function:

```
function HyperLink(elementID, url) {
    var textArea = $('#' + elementID);
    var len = textArea.val().length;
    var start = textArea[0].selectionStart;
    var end = textArea[0].selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end);
    var replacement = $('<div/>').append(
        $('<a/>').attr('href', url).html(selectedText)
    ).html();
    textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + replacement + textArea.val().substring(end, len));
}
```

**EDIT**

Seems that concatenating an `a` tag into a string gives just the url, so I wrapped it into a div and extracted its content to output it as a string.

**EDIT 2**
Seems that I copied a wrong version of the code. Sorry. Here's the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rok1ev0g/

Comment: Close, but this removes the selected text and inserts the url instead.

Comment: Sorry, seems that I copied a version prior final changes. Now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
$('#id_description').html('<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>');
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3sUvg/97/)**

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but here it goes:

```
var field = "http://www.google.com"
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.id_description').each(function () {
        this.innerHTML += ' <a href=" ' +field + '">Google</a>';
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3sUvg/100/)**

Comment: Right, but I need  links to be dynamically added to text, using an input window.

Comment: @Randi:- Updated my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately not· What I want is basically a functional `Insert Link` button that you find in any text editor, like here in SO.

Comment: @Randi:- So  you can do what epascarello has suggested, that would be easy and certainly do what you want!

Comment: I tried, but still could not implement it. js noob here!

Comment: @Randi:- Can you share the fiddle what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can give something a `href` by doing this in JavaScript:

```
element.href = "url";
```

In jQuery you can use:

```
element.attr('href', 'url');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery wrap()

```
$( "#id_description" ).wrap( '<a href="path"></a>' );
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

`<span class="linkable">Click to insert link</span>`

```
$('.linkable').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).html();
    var link = $("<a>", {
          href: "http://google.com"
        }).html(text);
    $(this).replaceWith(link);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dcjop9e7/)

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe this?](http://jsfiddle.net/8576xodd/3/)

```
$("textarea").on("select", function(){
    var start = this.selectionStart;
    var end = this.selectionEnd;

    var text = this.innerHTML.substring(start, end);
    var link = $("#user_link").val();

    var new_link ="<a href='"+link+"' target='_blank'>"+text+"</a>";


    $(this).after(new_link);
});
```

Comment: Well, I want user to let users to choose any part of the text and enclose it with any random url that they want. Just as you can do here.

Comment: As I said, users should be able to insert any link.